# (builtins.TypeError) SQLite Time type only accepts Python time objects as input

Tags: python, flask, time, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I try to make input time from HTML to sqlite using the Flask Login

This is model

```
class Shop(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shop'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    shop_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger)
    shop_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    shop_phone = db.Column(db.String(10))
    shop_email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    shop_calendarId = db.Column(db.String)
    shop_address = db.Column(db.String(300))
    shop_provinces = db.Column(db.String(20))
    shop_start_time = db.Column(db.Time)
    shop_end_time = db.Column(db.Time)
    shop_workers = db.Column(db.Integer)
    shop_slots = db.Column(db.Integer)
    shop_step_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    shop_duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    shop_web = db.Column(db.String)
    shop_fanpage = db.Column(db.String)
    shop_facebook_mes = db.Column(db.String)
    shop_logo = db.Column(db.String)
    shop_description = db.Column(db.String(300))
    shop_created_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    shop_ended_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    shop_token = db.Column(db.String)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.shop_id, self.__str__())
```

This is python code to get form

```
@main.route('/dashboard', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard_post():
    email = current_user.email
    shop = Shop.query.filter_by(shop_email=email).first()
    shop_workers = request.form.get('shop_workers')
    shop_slots = request.form.get('shop_slots')
    shop_step_time = request.form.get('shop_step_time')
    shop_duration = request.form.get('shop_duration')
    shop_provinces = request.form.get('shop_provinces')
    shop_address = request.form.get('shop_address')
    shop_phone = request.form.get('shop_phone')
    shop_token = request.form.get('shop_token')
    shop_name = request.form.get('shop_name')
    shop_start_time = request.form.get('shop_start_time')
    shop_end_time = request.form.get('shop_end_time')
    shop_web = request.form.get('shop_web')
    shop_fanpage = request.form.get('shop_fanpage')
    shop_facebook_mes = request.form.get('shop_facebook_mes')
    shop_logo = request.form.get('shop_logo')
    shop_description = request.form.get('shop_description')
    if shop_workers != '':
        shop.shop_workers = shop_workers
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_slots != '':
        shop.shop_slots = shop_slots
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_step_time != shop_step_time:
        shop.shop_step_time = shop_step_time
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_duration != '':
        shop.shop_duration = shop_duration
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_provinces !='':
        shop.shop_provinces = shop_provinces
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_phone !='':
        shop.shop_phone = shop_phone
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_address !='':
        shop.shop_address = shop_address
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_name !='':
        shop.shop_name = shop_name
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_address !='':
        shop.shop_address = shop_address
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_start_time !='':
        shop.shop_start_time = shop_start_time
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_end_time !='':
        shop.shop_end_time = shop_end_time
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_web !='':
        shop.shop_web = shop_web
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_fanpage !='':
        shop.shop_fanpage = shop_fanpage
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_facebook_mes !='':
        shop.shop_facebook_mes = shop_facebook_mes
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_logo !='':
        shop.shop_logo = shop_logo
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_description !='':
        shop.shop_description = shop_description
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard_redirect'))
```

This is html code

```
<div class="col"><label
                                            class="label-input-group">Giờ mở cửa: {{ shop_start_time }}</label>
                                        <div class=""><input id="shop_start_time" name="shop_start_time" type="Time"
                                                             class="next-input"
                                                             placeholder="{{ shop_start_time }}" step="1"
                                                             value="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col"><label
                                            class="label-input-group">Giờ đóng cửa: {{ shop_end_time }}</label>
                                        <div class=""><input id="shop_end_time" name="shop_end_time" type="Time"
                                                             class="next-input"
                                                             placeholder="{{ shop_end_time }}" step="1"
                                                             value="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

The eror come as below

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(builtins.TypeError) SQLite Time type only accepts Python time objects as input.
[SQL: UPDATE shop SET shop_start_time=? WHERE shop.id = ?]
[parameters: [{'shop_start_time': '08:00', 'shop_id_1': 1}]]
```

Any one help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception is raised because you tried to pass the string '08:00' directly from your input field to the object.

The object expects you to provide a `time` object such as objects created with `datetime`. [More about python's time objects.](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-time-object-in-Python.php). You can build these objects with e.g. [datetime's strptime](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm). If you want to have it parsed automatically take a look at [Flask wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, i change my code and it worked

```
  if shop_start_time !='':
        shop.shop_start_time = datetime.strptime(shop_start_time,"%H:%M").time()
        db.session.commit()
    if shop_end_time !='':
        shop.shop_end_time = datetime.strptime(shop_end_time,"%H:%M").time()
```